# Can I use OpenGL on a local Wamp server?

Tags: python, opengl, server, server-side, pyopengl

My project consists of a website where a user inputs a Music XML file and receives a video *(similar to synthesia)* based on that XML file. I am using python to parse the XML file and get all the useful information. With that information, I am using PyOpenGL with glut to create animations and OpenCV to save each frame to a video.

I am able to run the program locally and it works. Now I am trying to use the program within my Wamp Server. So my question is, how would I go about doing this? My plan was to call the program with PHPs  `shell_exec()` but nothing seems to happen. I've tested `shell_exec()` on simple test files that returns a string and that works. I have done some research and found I can use xvfb for headless server rendering. Any idea of how I can implement this with PyOpenGL/Glut? Also is it ok to use PHPs `shell_exec()` or should I be using something else to call my Python program?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost decide upon you need/want GPU acceleration or not. There's little use in trying to hone out a GPU accelerated OpenGL context creation, if your target system doesn't even have a GPU.

Next you should come to terms with, that you'll no longer be able to use GLUT, because GLUT was implemented with creating on-screen windows in mind.

If you can live without GPUs and rely on software rasterization, you should look into OSMesa https://mesa3d.org/osmesa.html

If you need GPU acceleration, check what GPU you'll be running on. If it's going to be a NVidia one, check out their excellent blog on how to create a headless rendering context with EGL https://devblogs.nvidia.com/egl-eye-opengl-visualization-without-x-server/

If it's an AMD or Intel GPU, then EGL in theory should work as well. However using DRM+GBM will usually yield better results. There's an example project for that to be found at https://github.com/eduble/gl

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've done some research on EGL and OSMesa and have found most examples on creating a headless rendering context with EGL are using C with a Linux/Ubuntu server. Will there be much of a difference when using wamp server instead of a Linux/Ubuntu server?

Comment: @ShayneM: OSMesa works pretty much the same in Windows as in Linux. However headless OpenGL GPU acceleration and Windows don't really go along very well. It's already difficult enough to do on Linux. **But** it'd be pretty much straightforward doing with Vulkan instead of OpenGL. As a matter of fact, Vulkan headless rendering involves zero OS dependent programming whatsoever!